# Google Drive API get authenticated email

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm running the php google drive api and I can authenticate the user just fine, but I want to store the user's permissionId and their email address into my database. the permissionid is easily accessible with

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
...
$permissionID = $service->about->get()->getpermissionId();
```

but there isn't anything like `getEmailAddress()` Does google drive have a return for the email address or do I need to extend the scope and access it elsewhere?

currently my scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

**EDIT**

just managed to do this by doing a get request with

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=
```

for people who have used this api before, is it better to store the PermissionId or the ID returned by the get request? I don't know what the difference between the two are

Comment: In the About resource there is a user obect which holds the values for "permissionId" and also "emailAddress". You can check the about resource in this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource Hope that helps!

Comment: how do you use `get()` to get the email address? because there is no `$service->user->get()->getId()` or `$service->about->user->get()->getId()`

Comment: nevermind just got it haha. `print_r($service->about->get()->getUser())` gets you the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$service->about->get()->getUser()->getemailAddress();
```

This will give you the email address of the user that is authenticated with your app.

As KRR mentioned above, visit [Google's Drive Api Reference Page](http://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource)  for more functions. Usually if you want to get a property value it is in the form of `get($propertyname)()`

Comment: Hi, this is for API v2. How do we do it in API v3?

Comment: @Vishnu, thats for API v2. For V3, check the answer i've posted.

Answer (score 1):

The answer CrudeCoder gave is correct for **Drive API v2**. For **Drive API V3** use:

```
$service->about->get(array('fields' => 'user'))->getUser()->getemailAddress();
```

In V3 you need to specify the fields params.

Comment: Thank you this's very helpful, The error really doesn't giving any clue that there's a array parameter fields on get() method. Where do you find thid docs anyway? Thank you